# How to exclude specific key from mongodb lookup in go?

Tags: mongodb, go

I have the logic to query data from MongoDB to produce Kafka messages. I want to exclude a specific key in MongoDB. **Please help.** (ex. key name: def)

```
    //1. search mongodb
    connetionMongodbInfo := common.MongodbIpInfo()
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(connetionMongodbInfo)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)
    if err != nil {return result, common.CCErrServiceUnavailable}
    defer client.Disconnect(context.TODO())
    backupCollection := client.Database(common.MongodbName()).Collection(common.MongodbCollection())
```

In the logic below, it seems that a statement excluding key def should be added.

```
    cursor, err := backupCollection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{{"abc",abc}})
    if err != nil {return result, common.CCErrServiceUnavailable}
```

Below is the logic to receive mongodb data and produce kafka message.

```
    //2. produce kafka message
    for cursor.Next(context.TODO()) {
        var elem bson.M
        err := cursor.Decode(&elem)
        if err != nil {return result, common.CCErrServiceUnavailable}
        JsonData, jsonErr := json.Marshal(elem)
        if jsonErr != nil {return result, common.CCErrServiceUnavailable}
        var data map[string]interface{}
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(JsonData), &data)enter code here
        str := fmt.Sprint(data["abc"])
        common.SendMessageAsync(topic, str, string(JsonData))
    }
```

Comment: To exclude documents where `key` is `def`, use a filter like `bson.M{"key": bson.M{"$ne": "def"}}`. If this does not answer your question, please provide more details in the question.